# G sheet How to jump over no value cells with SUMIF function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I would to get the sum of the duration of the column B

```
+---+----------+
| A | 14:45:00 |
+---+----------+
| A | #Value!  |
+---+----------+
| A | 13:34:50 |
+---+----------+
| B | 23:41:00 |
+---+----------+
| B | 43:46:00 |
+---+----------+
```

I'm using these functions :

`=SUMIF( A1:A5 ; "B" ;B1:B5 )` this one gives me the sum of time

`=SUMIF( A1:A5 ; "A" ;B1:B5 )` This one doesn't work because I've an Error with  #Value! in B2.

How to jump over the "#Value! Error" cells with SUMIF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two criteria:

- Must have `A` in **column A**
- **Column B** must have a value.

So, use `SUMIFS`

Formula:

`=SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,"A",B1:B5,">0")`

Here is the screenshot of where I used the formula:

[image: screenshot]

Also, make sure format is set to duration where you are performing the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula instead:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A1:B5,"where A='A'"))
```

[image: How to SUM the "#Value! Error" cells]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)